# Best way to structure code that calls a web service

Tags: c#, exception

I am calling a web service via a httpwebrequest,  and getting a response. The web service is meant to run 24/7.

What is the best way to structure this code, with checks that the service is "available"?

What I have:

```
if (NetworkIsAvailable())
{
  // Call web service
 // Handle exceptions within here.
}


else
{
 // to throw a relevant exception that there is no network
}
```

Is it wise to throw an exception, or just return false? The svc should never be down

Comment: It depends on what NetworkIsAvailable() is doing to see if it's available. An exception may be useful to actually log or display the reason of something being "available".  Nothing is ever 100% uptime, so it is very wise to check.

Comment: I personally run it in a try/catch. I catch the exception that the network is down, and return JSON stating such.

Comment: Unless you're absolutely sure you'll never need to know the reason why the call failed (unlikely), throw an exception. (Or return some sort of error code object if you feel like forcing the caller to handle a possible failure, but that's not really idiomatic in C#.) `false` and `null` are horrible error indicators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the type of data you are receiving back, the frequency of checks, etc I would use a general purpose solution that tries the connection multiple times on a failure and then categorizes "exceptions" on failure (no two exceptions are ever the same in my experience).

For instance:

```
var failCount = 0;
var succeeded = false;

while ((failCount < 3) && (!succceeded)) {
   try {
      //call service....
      succeeded = true;
   } catch(WebException wex) {
      //handle wex, for instance look for timeout and retry
   } catch(...) {
     //Handle other exceptions differently...
     LogError("BOOOM: " + excep);
     throw;
   } catch(Exception ex) {
     //handle a general exception
     failCount++;
   }
}

if (failCount >= 4) {
   //Unspecified error multiple times, react appropriately...
}
```

Obviously you dont want to do this multiple tries if its expensive call, here I assume its a sort of "heartbeat" check thats not too expensive. The "failCount" can be adjusted depending on how "turbulent" you expect the connection to be.

Comment: +1 Nice work treating exception types differently and retrying multiple times before exiting gracefully.

Comment: Thanks @Yuck, Nice company you work for, looks interesting. :)

Comment: Nice bimplementation. I guess I can catch exceptions and let the user retry, and let others which can't be handled bubble up.